# How to handle Angular Template when change value of variable? (async / await and for loop)

Tags: angular, async-await, promise

I make a Project which by firebase and Angular.

First this is my ts code.

```js
...
async ngOnInit() {
        this.email = await this.loginServise.userInfo();
        this.arrayBouquetName = await this.fireStore.collection("user").doc(this.email).get().toPromise();
        this.arrayBouquetName = await this.arrayBouquetName.get("src");
        this.arrayBouquetSrc = await this.getSrc();
        console.log(this.arrayBouquetSrc);
    }


    async getSrc() {
        return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
            for await (let item of this.arrayBouquetName){
                this.arrayBouquetSrc.push(item);
            }
            console.log("Does it work? : ",this.arrayBouquetSrc)
            resolve(this.arrayBouquetSrc);
        })
    }
...
```

and this is my template file (HTML)

```html
<div id="canvas-my-bouquet">
    <div id="container-my-bouquet">
        check it : {{arrayBouquetSrc}}
    </div>
</div>
```

When i run this code i can't see value of `arrayBouquetSrc` below picture
[image]
however,When i change `arrayBouquetSrc` => `arrayBouquetName`, I can see value of variable.
[image]
I don't know what is reason and how to solve this situation...
I know If i dynamic

Comment: Why are you modifying `arrayBouquetSrc` in `getSrc()`, and then returning the same array in order to assign it to the same variable again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `async` pipe [as recommended by angular](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe#examples):

```
private userInfo$: Observable<User>;
private bouquets$: Observable<Boucket[]>;
private boucketSources$: Observable<string[]>;

constructor(private fireStore: FireStore) {
    // Don't use toPromise inside this method
    this.userInfo$ = this.loginServise.userInfo();
    
    // When the userInfo$ changes, map it to get the documents from FireStore
    this.bouquets$ = this.userInfo$.pipe(map((userInfo) => {
        return this.fireStore.collection("user").doc(userInfo).get();
    }));

    // Then you want the names to be in a seperate variable
    this.boucketSources$ = this.bouquets$.pipe(map((bouckets) => {
        return bouckets.map(b => b.src);
    }));
}
```

Now you can use the `async` pipe in your template

```
<div id="canvas-my-bouquet">
    <div id="container-my-bouquet">
        <div *ngFor="let boucket of (boucketSources$ | async)" class="boucket">
            check it : {{boucket}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: replace your method.

```
...
async ngOnInit() {
        this.email = await this.loginServise.userInfo();
        this.arrayBouquetName = await this.fireStore.collection("user").doc(this.email).get().toPromise();
        this.arrayBouquetName = await this.arrayBouquetName.get("src"); // does this line work?
        this.fillArrayBouquetSrc();
        console.log(this.arrayBouquetSrc);
    }


    fillArrayBouquetSrc() {
         for (let item of this.arrayBouquetName){
           this.arrayBouquetSrc.push(item);
         }
         console.log("Does it work? : ",this.arrayBouquetSrc)
    }
...
```

NOTE: You dont need to make the method async. There is a synchronous operation. And do not return anythink from the mothod. Bcz of that it is already changing this.arrayBouquetSrc. It is available as this.arrayBouquetSrc in the class instance methods.